# Can anyone explain what is happening here object[val] = (object[val] || 0) + 1

Tags: javascript, function, object

I am practicing js and i encounter this line of code in a for each loop

```
function test(arr1){
  let fq1 = {}

  for(val of arr1){
    fq1[val] = (fq1[val] || 0) + 1
  }
}

test([1,2,3,3]);
```

i have provided the code what i encounter can anyone please exaplian what is happening in

```
fq1[val] = (fq1[val] || 0) + 1
```

i tried and i have seen the object key is storing the number of value are provided in array. But i am not clear about the line of code i have mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(fq1[val] || 0)
```

this means evaluate to the value on the left if it is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) (if converted to a boolean, it would be `true`), otherwise evaluate to the value on the right.

In this specific case, this is saying "evaluate to the value in object `fq1` at key `val`, however if it's `undefined` (not in the object yet) then use `0` as a default value"